# get files back added using tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have added files through tortoise svn in a folder. But by mistake I deleted the folder containing the files without committing. Can I get the files and folder back. My folder was already committed but files weren't.

Comment: You're out of luck with getting them back via Tortoise SVN, however the operating system of the system you are using may be able to offer some help. Unfortunately, because you haven't crossed our palms with enough info, your question can't really be answered in its current form. Try adding some detail to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately unless they were committed they're lost.

You can see what was committed with a `svn update`